# Plotting of a function

Tags: computational-physics

How to plot a complicated function in Desmos?
Such as the inter-atomic potential of NaCl which is

$ V(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon } \frac{Qna*Qcl}{x} +A\exp(\frac{-x}{B}) - \frac{C}{x^6}                                                        $

Comment: What's stopping you from just writing that out in Desmos?

Comment: I did not get what I was expecting

Comment: Its plot should look like the plot of central potential, but I do not know why it is plotting something else. Maybe because I did not specify the value of constants A, B, C. I want to view this potential at inter-atomic distance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qjkknqq4eb

Just change the constants and scale until you get what you want.  You can change the scale by clicking on the spanner symbol.

Comment: Quick Desmos tip: you can add sliders for constants like so: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdzhhbpgqd

Comment: @Nihar Karve, yes that might be useful